# Help on renaming a table field

Tags: database

I have temp table field : $field.'_temp'
I need to **rename** it as $field. {no other structure changes}

```
  db_drop_field($table, $field);
  db_change_field($table, $field . '_temp', $field, array('type' => 'int'));
```

This works fine!

I read in the documentation that is necessary

> IMPORTANT NOTE: To maintain database portability, 
>       you have to explicitly recreate all indices and primary keys 
>       that are using the changed field.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_change_field/7

As my table has many indeces like here below:
[image]

That means in order to maintain portability we need to drop indeces and recreate them using

db_drop_primary(), db_drop_index(), db_add_index() and db_add_primary_key()

it is not very clear how this should be done in the specific context (core table) and how would be the impact on other components.

Comment: [`db_drop_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_drop_index/7), [`db_add_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_index/7) and [`db_add_primary_key()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_primary_key/7)? Wait, that looks like a core field table - what exactly are you trying to do?! :)

Comment: @Clive It is true (it is a date field for articles). I am working on a migration hook_update_N to convert the current date stored in a format datetime to unix timestamp.

Comment: Why not just delete the field and start again? By changing the field type you're likely to truncate existing data anyway so it might be easier

Comment: @Clive, I did that already. Now I have the correct data in field_temp, therefore I need to delete field and rename field_temp as field. It seems I handle bad the db_change_field() method

Comment: Wow that's a difficult spot to be in. Personally I'd add the new field table through the UI, then use a `SELECT INTO` to import the data from the temp table. Then you can be sure the right indices have been created. Other than that, just copy the indices from another field table - they're all pretty much identical, the only ones that need to change are those prefixed with `field_name_`

Comment: @Clive The migration script will be run on dozen of websites. Moreover I will perform this on all tables which contain wrong data type. You mean to alter my script instead creating duplicate fields (field -> field->temp) to duplicate the whole table (table -> table->temp)? Won't be any performance issues?

Comment: Ah ok, I assumed you were running this on a single site. I'm afraid I can't really offer any advice on a performant way to do this across multiple sites. It's a complicated process; changing the data type of a column with knock-on effects on multiple production sites, especialy in an automated process, isn't really the best idea. So much can go wrong. Basically you're on the right track, you just need to check the indices on another field table and copy them across, changing the column names where appropriate, and use the 3 functions from the first comment as appropriate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10630/discussion-between-drupont-and-clive)

Comment: Sorry I'm in the office, can't chat. I don't really have anything else to suggest beyond what I've already said to be honest

Comment: @Clive I thank you, no need for a chat, was a mistake, I may only need to add db_drop_primary_key() to the collection